# reconfigure or uninstall opencv2 on ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I have opencv2 installed on ubuntu 14.04. I want to install it again with cuda turned off. How should I approach this?
My attempt:
find the path where opencv installed:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so'
```

I found where cv2.so is located:

```
$ sudo find / -name cv2.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
```

I also tried to locate other opencv files

```
$ sudo find / -name *opencv*
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv2.4-java.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv2.4-jni.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/opencv-data.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-opencv.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/opencv-data.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-flann2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv2.4-java.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-opencv.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-opencv.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-opencv.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-stitching2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ts2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-calib3d-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv2.4-jni.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ml-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-superres-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-core2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-gpu-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-features2d2.4:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-video2.4:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-videostab2.4:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-photo2.4:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-ocl2.4:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64.postrm
/usr/local/include/opencv2
/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv
/usr/local/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration
/usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation
/usr/local/bin/opencv_visualisation
/usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade
/usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples
/usr/local/bin/opencv_version
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.2
/usr/include/opencv2
/usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/usr/include/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp
/usr/include/opencv
/usr/bin/opencv_performance
/usr/bin/opencv_traincascade
/usr/bin/opencv_createsamples
/usr/bin/opencv_haartraining
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_haartraining.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_performance.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_createsamples.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_traincascade.1.gz
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libopencv2.4-jni
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libopencv-core-dev
/usr/share/java/opencv.jar
/usr/share/java/opencv-247.jar
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-objdetect-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-ocl-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-videostab-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-core2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-video-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-ml-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-gpu-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-objdetect2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-flann2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-ts2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-superres2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-features2d2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-imgproc-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-video2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-stitching-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-photo-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-ts-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv2.4-java
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-ml2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv2.4-jni
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-photo2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-videostab2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-stitching2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-gpu2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-flann-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-calib3d-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-ocl2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-imgproc2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui-dev
/usr/share/doc/opencv-data
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-superres-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-legacy2.4
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-features2d-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-core-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-legacy-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-calib3d2.4
/usr/share/doc/python-opencv
/usr/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-248.jar
/usr/share/opencv
/usr/lib/jni/libopencv_java248.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4
/home/ubuntu/src/mxnet/plugin/opencv
/home/ubuntu/src/mxnet/plugin/opencv/opencv.mk
/home/ubuntu/src/mxnet/plugin/opencv/opencv.py
/home/ubuntu/src/mxnet/cpp-package/example/feature_extract/prepare_data_with_opencv.cpp
/home/ubuntu/src/mxnet/tests/ci_build/install/install_opencv.sh
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-1.61.0-py35_0/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv.hpp
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-1.61.0-py35_0/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv.hpp
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda2/pkgs/boost-1.61.0-py27_0/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv.hpp
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda2/pkgs/boost-1.61.0-py27_0/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda2/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv.hpp
/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda2/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv
/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cntk/libs/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cntk/libs/libopencv_core.so.3.2
/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cntk/libs/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/libs/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/libs/libopencv_core.so.3.2
/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/libs/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
/home/ubuntu/src/theano/benchmark/convolution/opencv.py
/opt/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv.hpp
/opt/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv
/opt/opencv-3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv2
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/bin/opencv_annotation
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/bin/opencv_traincascade
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/bin/opencv_createsamples
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_core.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_features2d.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_video.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_ml.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_superres.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_flann.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudev.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudev.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_photo.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudacodec.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_shape.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_ts.a
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudev.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudacodec.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.1
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.1.0
/opt/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_cudacodec.so.3.1
```

How can I configure opencv with cuda off or how to uninstall it so I can install it again with the desired configurations?

Comment: How did you installed it in the first place? Did you cloned both `opencv` and `opencv-contrib` ?

Comment: I'm assuming you compiled this from source.  The only way for you to reconfigure / uninstall it is to recompile it from source with the CUDA CMake flags turned off, then recompile and finally reinstall the library.

Comment: I dont know how was it installed. @GrayCygnus . no search results for opencv-contrib

Comment: Pardon me but how can it be you "dont know" how it was installed? Anyways when I reinstalled my `OpenCV` I had to delete both the `opencv` and `opencv-contrib` folders, and then proceed with regular installation (following [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) tutorial)... Do you have any of those folders? If the tutorial is of help I could translate the instructions to an answer

Comment: @GaryCygnus I was not the one who installed it. I have opencv folders. I will try to uninstall using the answer described here https://askubuntu.com/a/579699/661714 but is there a way to pass a yes for all the prompts I get?

Comment: When I followed this answer along with the anser here http://www.answers.opencv.org/question/95022/how-to-uninstall-opencv-python/?answer=102123#post-id-102123 I get the following when importing cv2 in python "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>" Did I successfully remove opencv?
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: That completely removes OpenCV from your computer but you didn't remove the Python package from your `site-packages` in your Python distribution. Of course it can't find the shared libraries required to run it as you've removed them. You don't have a choice but to install it again from source.